# Shift Operator only working when shifting until 16 digits

Tags: javascript, binary, hex, shift

I have been trying to find the answer all morning, so happy to close this question if it is a duplicate. I am tying to get the first 2 digits of a hex number that has 8 digits.

I understand that `>>` moves x bits to the right. So doing `0b10 >> 1` ends up in `0b01`

All works for the last 6 digits.
The last 2 hex numbers:

```
0x000000FF >> 0 // 255
0b00000000000000000000000011111111 >> 0 == 0b00000000000000000000000011111111 // == 255
```

The 3th and 4th hex digit from the right:

```
0x0000ff00 >> 8 // 255
0b00000000000000001111111100000000 >> 8 == 0b00000000000000000000000011111111 // == 255
```

The 5th and the 6th hex from right:

```
0x00ff0000 >> 16
0b00000000111111110000000000000000 >> 16 == 0b00000000000000000000000011111111 // == 255
```

Trying to get the 7th and 8th hex number from the rigth, or the first 2 from the left should moving all bits 24 places to the right:

```
0xff000000 >> 24
0b11111111000000000000000000000000 >> 24 => Should be 255, but it is -1
```

How can I get `0b11111111000000000000000000000000` to become 255?

Comment: LOL, love that username. 90's reference! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is simple, the `>>` operator is a [signed shift operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Right_shift), so instead you would simply use [an unsigned version `>>>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unsigned_right_shift):

```js
console.log(0xff000000 >> 24)
console.log(0xff000000 >>> 24)
```